# Style The 1st Instance Of A <dt> Element Only, Without Physically Removing Styles From The 2nd Instance (& Without Adding Classes or IDs)

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a description list `<dl>` element whose inner `<dt>` element I've have styled. The description list sits inside a main `.content-wrapper` div.

I would like the CSS styling for the first `<dt>` element to NOT be applied to the one inside the `<article>` element which has a `<dl>` and an associated `<dt>` element also.

With CSS ( and without adding any classes or IDs ), is there a way of applying the CSS only to the `<dt>` element in the outer content wrapper part of the markup without physically removing the styles from the 2nd `<dt>` element?

I've tried playing around with `:not` and the `>` descendent selector, but I can't seem to get it work?

The CSS selector would be something like `dt:not(article > dt)`

Codepen: https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/pojYVZP

```css
.content-wrapper dt {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.2rem 0.4rem;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quis consequatur veritatis maxime iste architecto rerum, illo ex perspiciatis obcaecati! Minus ea architecto odit dicta alias eveniet reiciendis. Modi, sunt!</p>
  <dl>
    <dt>Just Style This</dt> <!-- ONLY ADD THE STYLING TO THIS <dt> ELEMENT -->
    <dd>Information</dd>
    <dd>Information</dd>
  </dl>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas provident neque soluta accusamus repellendus explicabo recusandae, nemo quis, fugiat dolorum rem est ipsam molestias velit vitae numquam iusto sapiente. Placeat!</p>
  <article>
    <dl>
      <dt>Do Not Style This</dt> <!-- DON'T ADD THE STYLING TO THIS ELEMENT -->
      <dd>Information inner</dd>
      <dd>Information inner</dd>
    </dl>
  </article>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be like this:

```css
.content-wrapper > dl dt {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.2rem 0.4rem;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem quis consequatur veritatis maxime iste architecto rerum, illo ex perspiciatis obcaecati! Minus ea architecto odit dicta alias eveniet reiciendis. Modi, sunt!</p>
  <dl>
    <dt>Just Style This</dt> <!-- ONLY ADD THE STYLING TO THIS <dt> ELEMENT -->
    <dd>Information</dd>
    <dd>Information</dd>
  </dl>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas provident neque soluta accusamus repellendus explicabo recusandae, nemo quis, fugiat dolorum rem est ipsam molestias velit vitae numquam iusto sapiente. Placeat!</p>
  <article>
    <dl>
      <dt>Do Not Style This</dt> <!-- DON'T ADD THE STYLING TO THIS ELEMENT -->
      <dd>Information inner</dd>
      <dd>Information inner</dd>
    </dl>
  </article>
</div>
```